# C++ variable that can be used in any file of the project

Tags: c++, class, header

I am making a C++ project with the main.cpp which has main function, then a header file header.h and a cpp file program.cpp which has class methods in it. So I wanted to ask is there  a way to declare a variable that i would use in main.cpp and methods could read it in program.cpp ?

Comment: maybe you shouldn't do it at all: see [c++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/global-vars.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Look up the `extern` keyword in your C++ book.

Comment: Also consider not doing it. This is called a global variable and as the program grows globals become easily abused and are a source of bugs, make testing harder and so on...

Comment: Here come the global police

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are discouraged in general, but you can do this simply with the following in your header file:

```
extern my_global_type myGlobal;
```

you then define `myGlobal` in `main.cpp` as:

```
my_global_type myGlobal = \* some init value *\;
```

and simply use it in `program.cpp` by including the header with the above `extern`.  You can make it a bit less global (but not get rid of all the problems) by putting `myGlobal` in a `namespace`.